# Vuejs - Passing props (from object) to child and back to parent

Tags: vue.js

I have a JSON object in the parent component eg. `[{type:"checkbox", allValues:["1", "2"], selectedValues:[]}]`. I want to render a child component that has a checkbox for each value of *allValues* and if a checkbox is checked, it saves the value in *selectedValues*. So far I have:

In Parent Component:

```
<inputCheckbox 
v-if="item.description.field === 'checkbox'" 
v-bind:selectedValues=item.selectedValues
v-bind:allValues=item.allValues>
</inputCheckbox>
```

In Child Component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, index) in this.$props.allValues" v-bind:key="index">
      <input type="checkbox" :value=item v-model="$props.selectedValues">
      <label>{{item}}</label>
    </div>
    {{$props.selectedValues}} ---> this works, I can see the array correctly filled 
  </div>  
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'InputCheckbox',
  props: [
    'allValues',
    'selectedValues'
  ]
}
</script>
```

but when I try `{{$props.selectedValues}}`   in the Parent Component, the array is empty.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: Communication in Vue: data from parent to child, events from child to parent. The [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Listening-to-Child-Components-Events) explain it in detail

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `v-model` in the component reference directly, i.e. `<InputCheckbox v-model="...">`, for two-way binding to work. And then internally within the `InputCheckbox` component itself, the `value` prop will be available as the bound value. If you are using checkboxes or radio buttons, you might want to use the `model` option and select another prop name instead, e.g. `checked`.

Then, in the child component, you simply need to listen to the `onInput`/`onChange` event and emit an `input` event. In the parent element, the `v-model` binding will listen to this custom event and update the parent data accordingly, thereby achieving two-way binding.

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
Vue.component('input-checkbox', {
  template: '#input-checkbox-template',
  model: {
    prop: 'checked',
  },
  props: {
    checked: Boolean
  },
  methods: {
    onInput(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.checked);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    myCustomToggle: true,
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Boolean toggle</h1>
  Value on the parent component: {{ myCustomToggle }}
  <br /><br />
  <!-- Use v-model on the parent component! -->
  <input-checkbox v-model="myCustomToggle" />
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="input-checkbox-template">
  <div class="box">
    <input type="checkbox" v-bind:checked="checked" v-on:input="onInput"/>
    <br />
    Value on the child component: {{ checked }}
  </div>
</script>
```

See more information on two-way binding for a prop: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model